# Do I need all database columns in my DataTable for SqlBulkCopy WriteToServer?

Tags: datatable, sqlbulkcopy

I'm importing some data from a CSV, and it doesn't have all the fields my table does.  I was making a DataTable with only the columns of my CSV, but I'm getting errors about converting from String to Boolean.  None of the fields I'm adding are Boolean, so I'm assuming its a problem with the fields I left alone.

Do I need to have a 1-1 mapping in my DataTable?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, once I added all the columns, things started working, so I guess the answer is yes.